# How to configure Bind9 to return a fixed IP on non-exist request?

Tags: domain, bind

I want that Bind9 returns a fixed IP to the clients when them request invalid(non-exist) domain name to it.
For example:
Client requests the doesnotexist.co domain. This domain is not found by the Bind9 search than in these cases Bind9 returns a fixed IP (aka 10.0.0.1) and not a domain_does_not_exist for the client.

Comment: Don't [hijack the DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking). People will rightly hate you for doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server is not authoritative for a zone for which it is polled, it should either point to authoritative nameservers or return an error. Masquerading as authoritative for Internet zones poses a security risk even if done with the best intentions.

Doing so on a private network, as the local subnet IP in your question suggests, might appear to pose a considerably lower security risk, however even with the best intentions, an adversary could exploit this universal redirect in collaboration with encryption vulerabilities, or, for example, today, with Heartbleed-compromised SSL encryption, to capture and retransmit sensitive informations sent over an HTTPS connection.

This is the beauty of BIND9 and standards-oriented server daemons: they promote the standards that we rely on, and that already have low-level security considerations manage.

DNSSEC signed zones improperly replicated on a masquerading DNS sever, like the one you suggest, could trigger a cascade of blacklisting of public IP addresses and hostnames associated with such a server. Other legal and regulatory restrictions may also apply depending on your jurisdiction.

If you intend to do this on a closed, private network, it could be possible with BIND9 following the scheme used by providers of [alternative DNS root zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_DNS_root). However, again, I must stress that what you are proposing is highly unadvisable except in a closed network that is not connected to the Internet; however that in turn raises the question of the non-malicious usefulness of redirecting requests for Internet (i.e. non-private) DNS zones made on a closed, private network.

---

**2014-04-16** *@EricoSchuh provided more information:*

Inside a corporate environment, redirecting 404 requests from outside the Internet is often best achieved by isolating the internal network from the Internet, then by exception providing Internet access through a series of firewall and proxy appliances, applied through  client-side proxy settings, for example, in Windows environments using GPO or PowerShell. In this type of environment, the system administrators can easily redirect any client request, especially as in your case, for an network-internal search page.

The below simplified diagram from [a question on the Information Security Stack Exchange community](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/public-dmz-network-architecture) demonstrates the ideal holistic network architecture for having a DMZ with proxy servers.

[image: Image demonstrating Internet to Firewall to DMZ Servers to Firewall to Clients.]

Comment: Add: that will be only inside the company, to redirect to an internal search server that will help the user. Actually the bind server is used only as a internal DNS server, with no public  access.

Comment: 'Alternative DNS root' is the solution that I´m looking for. Thanks Guy Hughes

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with bind (you can trick it to always return the same IP for any host that it is not authoritative for by creating a "." zone and put wildcards inside it like *, *.*, *.*.* etc but if it is a recursive nameserver, it will not work). You can do it with [DNSMasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).

Comment: DNSMasq may be a option if Bind doesen't reach the need.